# Integrate ODE with Leapfrog

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, hamilton-equations

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function with gradient $g(x)$ and Hessian $H(x)$.
My initial conditions are $(x_0, v_0)$. I would like to discretize this system of ODEs
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x(t) &= v(t) \\
\dot v(t) &= a(x(t), v(t)) && \text{where } \qquad a(t, x(t)) = - \frac{v(t)^\top H(x(t)) v(t)}{||g(x(t))||} g(x(t))
\end{align}
$$
How can I do that? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) I could use the Leapfrog integrator, which would look like this
$$
\begin{align}
v_{t + \delta/2} &= v_t + \frac{\delta}{2} a(x_t, v_t) \\
x_{t + \delta} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2} v_{t+\delta/2} \\
v_{t + \delta} &= v_{t+\delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2}a(x_{t+\delta}, v_{t+\delta})
\end{align}
$$
However it seems that the leapfrog can't be used for cases where the acceleration depends on the velocity? Is this true? In that case, what would a good scheme look like? In the notes I am reading they use
$$
\begin{align}
x_{t+\delta/2} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2} v_t \\
v_{t+\delta} &= v_t + \delta a(x_{t+\delta/2}, v_t) \\
x_{t+\delta} &= x_{t+\delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2}v_{t+\delta/2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What's the problem with your namesake discretization of ODEs?

Comment: Well basically the Leapfrog method above does 1) half a velocity step, 2) full position step 3) half velocity step. However in the notes I am reading they give a discretization of this ODE system where one starts by doing half a position step, full velocity step and half a position step. They also seem to imply the scheme above is wrong...

Comment: @Ilya in the notes I am reading they use 
$$
\begin{align}
x_{t+\delta/2} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2} v_t \\
v_{t+\delta} &= v_t + \delta a(x_{t+\delta/2}, v_t) \\
x_{t+\delta} &= x_{t+\delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2}v_{t+\delta/2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I meant a simple Euler method

Comment: @Ilya would that be okay in this scenario though?

Comment: This scheme is probably slightly better than a pure Euler step, but still only order-1 consistent, only with better constants. While Euler is a move along the tangent, which leads mostly away from the solution, this will make the step more secant-like.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Do you mind explaining a bit more? I am very new to this world and I couldn't be more lost honestly